# Putting :base after function?

Tags: c#, .net

```
 public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string displayNameKey)
            : base(displayNameKey)
        {

        }
```

if i put `:base` after the function in the class what does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

[`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) indicates that you're calling the base class' constructor from this class' constructor.

It is only valid for constructors, not regular methods.  In your case, when a `LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute` is created, it passes the `displayNameKey` parameter to its base class' constructor.

Comment: which is sometime not optional ... the constructor of a base class could require arguments ...

Answer (score 3):

It means that you will invoke the according constructor of the base class of your class.

Consider this:

```
public class A {
  public A() {
    Console.WriteLine("You called the first constructor");
  }
  public A(int x) {
    Console.WriteLine("You called the second constructor with " + x);
  }
}

public class B : A {
  public B() : base() { } // Calls the A() constructor
}

public class C : A {
  public C() : base(10) { } // Calls the A(int x) constructor
}

public class D : A {
  public D() { } // No explicit base call; Will call the A() constructor
}


...
new B(); // Will print "You called the first constructor"
new C(); // Will print "You called the second constructor with 10"
new D(); // Will print "You called the first constructor"
```

If this still doesn't make any sense, you should probably read a bit more about constructors in object oriented languages, for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a [Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) and not a function or method (a constructor is a special method that is called automatically when your class is instantiated). Adding `:base`(parameter) after the constructor allows you to call the constructor of the base class (the class your class inherited from) with the parameter passed into your class constructor.

A good tutorial on constructors can be found at http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html which should help clear this up.